# Parse groovy script syntactically

Tags: parsing, groovy

Unable to parse (check for syntax) for groovy code. `parse()` method doesn't throw any exception but while executing it throws Exception

```
GroovyShell gEngine = new GroovyShell(); 
gEngine.evaluate("def n;  print ddd"); // throws an exception
gEngine.parse("def n; print ddd"); // don't throws Excption
```

Comment: `parse` doesn't try to run the script, `evaluate` does.  There is no problem syntactically with that code.  But there is logically.  Not sure what the question is?

Comment: its throwing exception at run time , cant it throw exception at compile time, because i dont want code to b executed.

Comment: But that script is fine. `ddd` might be added to the script at run time, so it would work.  So at compile time, there are no errors with it...

Answer (score 0):

From the groovy API:

[`parse`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GroovyShell.html#parse(java.lang.String))

> Parses the given script and returns it ready to be run

[`evaluate`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GroovyShell.html#evaluate(java.lang.String))

> Evaluates some script against the current Binding and returns the result

As @tim_yates notes in his comment, `evaluate` run the script while `parse` return a script object without running it, this is why `evaluate` throws the exception: `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: ddd`

However if you run the script returned by `parse` it will throw the same exception:

```
GroovyShell gEngine = new GroovyShell()
def script = gEngine.parse("def n; print ddd")
script.run() // throws missingPropertyException
```

Comment: yes script.run()   actually run the script and throws exception, but i am expecting ,before running script  could it be throws exception. In above case we need to run the script,  i want exception in compile time

Comment: There's no exception at compile time.  Syntactically, that is a perfectly fine script.  `ddd` may be added to the meta-class of the script at run time, so Groovy can't say it will fail at compile time

Comment: @tim_yates you're always right... and as usual with a prefect understandable explanation `:)`!

Comment: @tim_yates , now I get the point and understood it, Thanks for nice explanation tim_yates